# Typescript: Get correct member type from super call argument in derived class

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract class "Base"

```
abstract class Base {
  constructor(public readonly data: {
    [key: string]: BaseValue
  }) {}
}
```

and a derived class "Derived":

```
class Derived extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super({
      test: SpecialValue
    } as const);
  }
}
```

where `SpecialValue` extends `BaseValue`.

Is there a way to call `this.data["test"]` in the derived class and have `SpecialValue` as type?
I always get `BaseValue` as type.

What I don't want:
Introduce a generic Type on `Base` which types the data field like `class Derived extends Base<CorrectDataType>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For concreteness, I'm introducing the following definitions so your code constitutes a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
interface BaseValue {
    a: string;
}
interface SpecialValue extends BaseValue {
    b: number;
}
declare const SpecialValue: SpecialValue;
```

One thing to notice is that, with the following code:

```
const baseVals: {[k: string]: BaseValue} = { test: SpecialValue };
```

the compiler does not and cannot know that `baseVals.test` is of type `SpecialValue`.  The annotation of `{[k: string]: BaseValue}` is wider than that and allows for mutations, like

```
baseVals.foo = { a: "hello" };
baseVals.test = { a: "goodbye" };
```

So the compiler does not infer that `Derived`'s `data` has a `test` property of type `SpecialValue` just because it is constructed with one. If you want the compiler to know that, you have to tell it.

One way to do that is to make `Base` be generic in its `data` property type.  But you said you don't want that.

Another way is to explicitly narrow the type of `data` in `Derived` via a [a `declare` property modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier):

```
class Derived extends Base {
    declare readonly data: { test: SpecialValue };
    constructor() {
        super({
            test: SpecialValue
        } as const);
    }
}
```

This will now have the effect you want, (but be careful... the declaration is not type safe; you can `declare readonly data: { oops: SomeOtherSubtypeOfBaseValue }` and the compiler will not complain about the `super()` call.)  Observe:

```
const d = new Derived();
d.data.test.b.toFixed(); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QGpwDYCuKA3gLABQyVycAXMhmFKAOYDcFAvshaJLIhQBlAA4QEwfLkIoIAD0ggAJhjSYc+IsjKVqAI3ogCAWz3QO5ThSXi8cKCgQB7EI2SjxkvNKL0PEqU0ICwpnVzBkPXVpDHpiZABtAGt6RmYQFgBdenQsHxRuAF5tZEhGPzEA7yDkTgsovPwMADoYJydkYvi6ZAAiAAsIPDwnXtr66KbmsoiumnpelnalPQBPCDG6igo4PTTECIQ7DFVckgpqZDC0ggQwJygAChECPTxgBGQHOCUXPFXkEo4GAejpLpdkhBVqkmKxsmpGjILtROABKEpWSwhchHTCqAAi0GAADcIEpkPJFCoEeddFQbLiHF8ID8-gCgSC4qUIOV3JUvPlxsiqNcmLd7k90WDwVQMAQxE9pTLLjMKp5Aki6eDuJgri5GKiLJdMZjQvqIuTiiAIAB3ZCE5ikpSPQ3WZocuDTHlgZp6aZOABiwDkZJdbGQAHoI8gnEk4KsKEA)

Comment: thanks for you in depth answer.
i thought that the compiler could induce the `data` member type form the constructor argument and then also narrow this type, by the argument given in the super call.
i thought the `as const` assertion could narrow the object type given down enough.
..but im still learning and think that i didn't grasp the logical limitations of typescripts typesystem yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast to `SpecialValue`. Keep in mind that while this allowed by Typescript, it's usually not allowed by linters.

```js
const derivedValue: SpecialValue = <SpecialValue> this.data["test"]

// or...

const derivedValue: SpecialValue = this.data["test"] as SpecialValue
```

The compiler just won't be smart enough to see that `this.data["test"]` was set as a `SpecialValue` otherwise. The indexer in `Base` is trying to guarantee that all values are `BaseValue`s, so this is reasonable behaviour on the compiler's side I think.

Edit: I just saw jcalz's comment to your post, and that's definitely a better approach for most cases.